# MySQL Join even if there is no matching data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working to join the contents of my table, even when data is missing for some columns in the Join.  I got it to work partially  but the data where the one column is missing data to join with is swapped.

I've included my test table, row inserts and query I am working with.

--Test Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestTable` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Data` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `LastModified` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--Test Table Data

```
INSERT INTO `TestTable` (`ID`, `Data`, `LastModified`) VALUES
(1, 2480, '2014-05-20 00:00:00'),
(1, 2500, '2014-05-21 00:00:00'),
(2, 4560, '2014-05-20 00:00:00'),
(2, 8542, '2014-05-21 00:00:00'),
(3, 4587, '2014-05-21 00:00:00'),
(4, 2561, '2014-05-20 00:00:00'),
(4, 2561, '2014-05-21 00:00:00');
```

--Table Contents

```
ID  Data    LastModified
1   2480    2014-05-20 00:00:00
1   2500    2014-05-21 00:00:00
2   4560    2014-05-20 00:00:00
2   8542    2014-05-21 00:00:00
3   4587    2014-05-21 00:00:00
4   2561    2014-05-20 00:00:00
4   2561    2014-05-21 00:00:00
```

--Query I'm working with

```
SELECT `t1`.`ID`, `t1`.`Data`, `t1`.`LastModified`, `t2`.`ID`, `t2`.`Data`, `t2`.`LastModified`
FROM `TestTable` AS `t1`
LEFT JOIN `TestTable` AS `t2`
ON (`t1`.`ID` = `t2`.`ID`)
AND DATE(`t1`.`LastModified`) = '2014-05-20'
AND DATE(`t2`.`LastModified`) = '2014-05-21'
GROUP BY `t1`.`ID`
ORDER BY `t1`.`ID` ASC
```

--Query Results

```
ID  Data    LastModified    ID  Data    LastModified
1   2480    2014-05-20 00:00:00 1   2500    2014-05-21 00:00:00
2   4560    2014-05-20 00:00:00 2   8542    2014-05-21 00:00:00
3   4587    2014-05-21 00:00:00 NULL    NULL    NULL
4   2561    2014-05-20 00:00:00 4   2561    2014-05-21 00:00:00
```

--Results I'm trying to get, columns switched for ID 3

```
ID      Data    LastModified        ID  Data    LastModified
1       2480    2014-05-20 00:00:00 1   2500    2014-05-21 00:00:00
2       4560    2014-05-20 00:00:00 2   8542    2014-05-21 00:00:00
NULL    NULL    NULL                3   4587    2014-05-21 00:00:00
4       2561    2014-05-20 00:00:00 4   2561    2014-05-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: What are you trying to actually accomplish?  Can you describe the logic?

Comment: Joining of the 'Data' from two different days to compare the difference from day to day. Ex. 5-20-14 1000 - 5-21-14 3000 -> Difference of 2000 (The difference does not need to be shown in query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to keep all the `id`s and then look at the matches on the two days.  To do such a query, start with all the ids and then use `left join` to match to each condition:

```
SELECT `t1`.`ID`, `t1`.`Data`, `t1`.`LastModified`,
       `t2`.`ID` as id2, `t2`.`Data` as data2, `t2`.`LastModified` as LastModified2
FROM (select distinct id from TestTable) ids left outer join
     `TestTable` `t1`
     on ids.id = t1.id and DATE(`t1`.`LastModified`) = '2014-05-20' left outer join
     `TestTable` `t2`
     on ids.`ID` = `t2`.`ID` and DATE(`t2`.`LastModified`) = '2014-05-21'
GROUP BY ids.`ID`
ORDER BY ids.`ID` ASC;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ee38/4).

EDIT:

SGeddes makes a really good point.  The `group by` is unnecessary:

```
SELECT `t1`.`ID`, `t1`.`Data`, `t1`.`LastModified`,
       `t2`.`ID` as id2, `t2`.`Data` as data2, `t2`.`LastModified` as LastModified2
FROM (select distinct id from TestTable) ids left outer join
     `TestTable` `t1`
     on ids.id = t1.id and DATE(`t1`.`LastModified`) = '2014-05-20' left outer join
     `TestTable` `t2`
     on ids.`ID` = `t2`.`ID` and DATE(`t2`.`LastModified`) = '2014-05-21'
ORDER BY ids.`ID` ASC;
```

Comment: This works perfect, thank you so much! Also the SQL Fiddle is appreciated.

Comment: +1 -- But, I'm not sure you need the subquery while using `group by`.  This is what I did: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5aec1/10

Comment: @sgeddes . . . You have a good point.  The aggregation is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a right join?

```
SELECT `t1`.`ID`, `t1`.`Data`, `t1`.`LastModified`, `t2`.`ID`, `t2`.`Data`, `t2`.`LastModified`
FROM `TestTable` AS `t1`
RIGHT JOIN `TestTable` AS `t2`
ON (`t1`.`ID` = `t2`.`ID`)
AND DATE(`t1`.`LastModified`) = '2014-05-20'
AND DATE(`t2`.`LastModified`) = '2014-05-21'
GROUP BY `t1`.`ID`
ORDER BY `t1`.`ID` ASC
```

Otherwise, if you want to show every date that appears in either t1 or t2, try a `full outer join`. If you want *every* date to show up (even ones that don't show up in any table), you need to join on an extra (temporary) table with the dates

Comment: That does not show the data correctly. I'm only looking to show data for the 2 dates in the query, not every date I may have in the table.